# Yolo : How can yolo read hundreds of images at once?

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo

I want to use yolo to detect thousands of images at once using the GPU to optimize the detect speed. How can yolo read hundreds of images at once?

I have about 10TB image data, my problem is to extract the image information, I use the Yolo model to do the job of detect the object that I need. Everything is fine with detecting images one by one, but with 10TB image data extracting each image makes it work so that I can handle all the heap, which is a long time according to my computer calculations, I will It took about 9 months to finish extracting the above images.
I do use python multithread but the speed results don't improve too much. So I think there is an approach that Yolo will detect batchs of image data (the GPU will process hundreds of images at the same time do it for me, which helps me reduce the time I spend dealing with stacks of images). on).
I am writing this question, hope you can suggest how to process hundreds of images at once using the GPU to optimize the detection of yolo.
Thanks

Answer (score -2):

There is a yolo model that uses the GPU.

```
#GPU version
pip3 install yolo34py-gpu
```

I found it on this website
https://cloudxlab.com/blog/object-detection-yolo-and-python-pydarknet/

Comment: i am using Yolov5, Yolo3 not my version :(